# Cutting of tree at hudaibiah where historical pledge took place?

Tags: history, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, belief, tawheed

What is genuineness of narration/report which approximately says that Umer(May Allah be pleased with him) cut down the tree at hudaibia in order to prevent people from committing acts of innovation ?

The tree under which approximately 1400 companions(May Allah be pleased with all of them) pledged with Prophet(Peace be upon him)

Comment: There are many ahadith and narrations saying otherwise and there are a few narrations saying so.